# How is a funeral held without a minyan?

Tags: minyan, funeral-burial-levaya

This issue especially concerns the reading of Kaddish after Ha-Kvura.

Comment: I imagine that kaddish would be omitted in that scenario. Do you suspect otherwise?

Comment: The rest of the arrangement is the same, though. It's still a Jewish funeral!

Comment: Though not specific to the mourner's qaddish, the Sefer Hasidim generically suggests reciting the following three passages whenever one is unable to be with a minyan for qaddish: Numbers 14:17, Ezekiel 38:23, Psalms 113:2. ועתה יגדל נא כח ה' כאשר דברת לאמר  - והתגדלתי והתקדשתי ונודעתי לעיני גוים רבים וידעו כי שמי ה' - יהי שם ה' מבורך מעתה ועד עולם

Answer (score 4):

The halacha is clear that we do not say Kaddish with less than 10 males (M. Soferim 10:6, H. Tefillah 8:4-5, Tur and [SA OC 55:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.55.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). It is no different when holding a funeral. See for instance what R Yaakov Goldstein writes in The laws of customs and mourning, [vol 1, ch. 8, section I](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-8-funeral-burial/)

> Immediately following the completion of the burial [i.e. forming of
> the mound on the grave, and recital of Tziduk Hadin and Mizmor 49], it
> is customary [for the male mourners] to recite the specially
> formulated Kaddish, which includes a stanza of “Asid L’Ischadata Alma”
> and is thus called by this name. [...] **It may only be said if a
> Minyan is present, as is the rule by any Kaddish.**

Similarly R Maurice Lamm writes in The Jewish Way in Death and Mourning, p. 66 ([here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281569/jewish/A-Jewish-Burial-and-Procession.htm#ThePostBurial))

> **Kaddish is not recited at all when the grave cannot be filled in the
> presence of a minyan.**